# How to use executeAsync in nightwatch.js?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I want do some automated testing useing nightwatch:

```
this.demoTest = function (browser) {
    browser.executeAsync(function(data, done) {
        someAsyncOperation(function() {
        done(true);
    });
    }, [imagedata], function(result) {
        // ...
    });
};
```

But I don't know how to use executeAsync, flowing is my code:

```
module.exports = {
    'Demo asynchronous' : function(client){
        client.url(client.launchUrl);
        client.executeAsync(function(data, done) {
            someAsyncOperation(function() {
                client.setValue('#PoiSearch', data); 
                client.click('#POISearchButton');
                done(true);
        });
        }, ['hotle'], function(result) {
            client.expect.element('#Map div[name*="mark"]').to.be.present;
        });
    }
}
```

I just want to input a word, than click the search button, as a result I want to know the DOM have the special element .but I don't konw how to use executeAsync.

Answer (score 2):

The function you are passing to `executeAsync` gets executed as if it was in the javascript console of the browser your controlling (where everything else is executed in the node / selenium context. Because of this, you don't have access to the `client` variable inside of the `executeAsync` function.

If you want to wait to populate those fields using the nightwatch API, you could do something more like:

```

```
module.exports = {
    'Demo asynchronous' : function(client){
        client.url(client.launchUrl);
        client.executeAsync(function(data, done) {
            // start executing in the browser, no access to outside variables
            someAsyncOperation(function() {                
                done(true);
            });              
        });
        // end executing in the browser, back in the node context
        client.setValue('#PoiSearch', 'hotle'); 
        client.click('#POISearchButton');;
        client.expect.element('#Map div[name*="mark"]').to.be.present;
    }
}
```

```